# Finding a way to use System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvCdecl in Compact Framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework, il

The `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallConvCdecl` doesn't exist in the .Net Compact Framework.

Is there anyway to replicate this function in the Compact Framework?

Answer (score 2):

Windows CE does not have different calling conventions, so there is no need to specify one. Calling conventions are only applicable to 32-bit x86 code on Windows. All other platforms (including x64) have a single calling convention.

Since there was no need for it, it was omitted from Compact Framework (small runtime size was one of the design goals).

In addition, Compact Framework can't do dynamic compilation, so very little of the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` namespace is present.

Answer (score 1):

For the compact framework you use `CallingConvention.Winapi` which maps to cdecl.